# Deserialize DTO with jhipster's StringFilter

Tags: spring, jackson, jhipster

I have endpoint that i send data from other `backend`:

```
@GetMapping("/")
@PageableAsQueryParam
public ResponseEntity<Page<Dto>> getAll(
        @RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,
        @RequestParam("page") Integer page,
        @RequestParam("pageSize") Integer pageSize,
        String criteria
) throws IOException {
```

I see in debug that `String` `criteria` has data:

```
DocCriteria(id=null, symbol=StringFilter [contains=abcdef, ])
```

After changing `String criteria` to: `DocCriteria criteria`
In `debug` i see that all fields of `DocCriteria` are `null`.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.jackson.Jacksonized;
import tech.jhipster.service.Criteria;
import tech.jhipster.service.filter.InstantFilter;
import tech.jhipster.service.filter.LongFilter;
import tech.jhipster.service.filter.StringFilter;
import tech.jhipster.service.Criteria;
import lombok.Data;

import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Jacksonized
public class DocCriteria implements Serializable, Criteria {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LongFilter id;
    private StringFilter symbol;
}
```

I also tried to `serialize` object from `String`:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
final DocCriteria pojo = objectMapper.convertValue(criteria, DocCriteria.class);
```

But then i have got an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `...DocCriteria$DocCriteriaBuilder` 
(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
 ('DocCriteria(id=null, symbol=StringFilter [contains=abcdef, ]')
```

What should i do to make `Spring` `deserialize` that object correctly ?

```
<spring-boot.version>2.6.6</spring-boot.version>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhipster-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

EDIT:
without using lombok:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import tech.jhipster.service.Criteria;
import tech.jhipster.service.filter.InstantFilter;
import tech.jhipster.service.filter.LongFilter;
import tech.jhipster.service.Criteria;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class DocCriteria implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private LongFilter id;
    private StringFilter symbol;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        DocCriteria that = (DocCriteria) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, that.id) && Objects.equals(symbol, that.symbol);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, symbol);
    }

    public LongFilter getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(LongFilter id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public StringFilter getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(StringFilter symbol) {
        this.symbol= symbol;
    }

     public DocCriteria() {
    }

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public DocCriteria(
            @JsonProperty("id") LongFilter id,
            @JsonProperty("symbol") StringFilter symbol,
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

}
```

I have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe a Lombok issue? JHipster does not use Lombok, why tagging your question as jhipster?

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I tagged my question as `JHipster` cause `StringFilter` comes from `Jhipster` Library. Why `Lombok` issue? `Lombok` just removes `boilerplate` code and generates `setters` etc. I think due to `@Data` annotation.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I have added an example to the `question` without `lombok`, the issue still occurs, `lombok` does not matter here.